# How to Fetch the ICNO and Count(ICNO) in Mysql for the following Table based on Given Condition?

Tags: mysql

Question:
I have the table tbl_studentapplication as bellow and possible
values for column idprogram are (1,2,3,4)

```
idapplication   ICNO    IdProgram
```

```
 1              123      1
 2              345      2
 3              123      3
 4              345      4
 5              1234     3
```

How to fetch the ICNO and count(ICNO) from the table where idprogram in(3,4) only(ie do not fetch ICNO if ICNO belongs to idprogram in(1,2))

I have tried by using subquery in mysql but due to big table its taking more execution time and getting output nothing (**table consist almost 30 columns and one lac rows**).

**output:**

```
ICNO        count(ICNO)
```

```
1234           1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
SELECT ICNO, count(ICNO)
FROM tbl_studentapplication
WHERE ICNO NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT ICNO
    FROM tbl_studentapplication
    WHERE IdProgram IN (1,2)
)
GROUP BY ICNO
```

You might want to build an index on IdProgram and ICNO to make this query faster

Comment: for your query you will get last 3 rows from the above table I need only ICNO and count where ICNO belongs to idprogram 3 or 4 and not belongs to 1,2

Comment: Then you can use this?

SELECT ICNO, count(ICNO) FROM tbl_studentapplication WHERE ICNO NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT ICNO FROM tbl_studentapplication WHERE IdProgram IN (1,2)) a

Comment: Yes i had executed your Query but nothing is displayed in PHPMYADMIN   I think i need to add index as you told

Comment: When I use the data provided by you, and run the query on it, i have the correct results, i will update my answer to it

Comment: Once again i will check it out and confirm the same I am very thankfull to you.